# Where are neovim's cached, file-specific settings?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-system

Vim has a `~/.vim/view/` directory for storing file-specific settings, such as saved cursor position and any command manually ran while viewing a file. Sometime, when I would update and source my `vimrc`, my changes would be overwritten by the "cached" settings in `view/`, so it was necessary to delete the view file before my new `vimrc` could be sourced correctly in certain cases.

Where are the analogous `view/` settings for **neovim**?

I removed a plugin from my `init.vim`, but the plugin is still loaded when I open project files. If I create and open a new file, my `init.vim` is sourced correctly. Thus, neovim must be caching old settings somewhere. **How can I clear this cache?**

Thank you in advance.

(FYI: I've been using vim for 4 years and switched to neovim about a month ago)

Comment: Note that is "overriding" behavior should only happen if you have an autocommand that does `:loadview`, which I advise against for this reason :) sessions are better, IMO. Then there's also viminfo, which in neovim is called the shada file I think

Comment: I agree with your opinion completely. My problem was troublesome because I do not use `loadview`. The accepted answer by Matt is correct, but it turns out that my problem was not related to `viewdir` after all. I discovered a coc plugin (which I forgot I had) that was interfering with my other plugin. Removed the coc plugin and problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:h 'viewdir'` and `:set viewdir?` This is the same option for both Vim and Neovim, but Neovim has different default settings.